# Implementing a loop in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm curious about implementing a loop in Haskell. How can I do something similar in Haskell (pseudo-code):

```
var i = 0
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 10; i1++) {
  println(i1)
  i += 2
}

println(i)
```

Comment: you are printing i1 that is never incremented

Comment: @Arjan, I just fixed it.

Comment: Um, Haskell was designed *not* to do this.  Providing ways of iterating over structured data *without* reassignable variables or side effects is a large part of what Haskell is *for*.  Recursive functions can look a bit like this kind of loop, but aren't.  What part of the construct do you want to implement in Haskell - the reassignable variable or the loop block structure?

Comment: @itsbruce, re-read the question.

Comment: I did. Answer mine; which parts of your pseudo code are most important to you? You can *simulate* some bits but others -e.g.  the reassignable variable being updated within in the loop - not at all. So the question then is how much of an approximation is acceptable,  by your terms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In functional terms what you are doing is folding over a list of integers so that for each integer you print the element and increase an accumulator by 2. Since we are printing something (i.e. doing I/O) we need to [fold in a monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v%3afoldM) but otherwise it's just your standard [left-fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29).

```
foldM (\i i1 -> print i1 >> return (i + 2)) 0 [0..9] >>= print
```

We fold with a lambda function that uses the same variable names as your code. I.e. `i1` is the current element and `i` is the accumulator.

The next parameter is the initial value for the accumulator which corresponds to `i = 0` in your code.

The final parameter is the (inclusive on both ends) list of numbers we fold over.

The `>>=` (bind operator) pipes the result of the fold (i.e. the final value of the accumulator `i`) to the print function.

EDIT: This is assuming that you meant to write

```
var i = 0
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 10; i1++) {
  println(i1)
  i += 2
}

println(i)
```

instead of incrementing just `i` in both the for-clause and loop body.

Comment: Nice to see the "Haskell" way of doing it in 1 line instead of 5 :)

Comment: This solution works without binding the `Int` values to the print function via `>>= print`.

Answer (score 7):

Going by the two assumptions that

1. By "similar" you mean similar in behaviour, and
2. (the same assumption shang made) that you want to print out

   ```
   0
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   20
   ```

I would in Haskell write

```
do
  let xs = [0..9]
  mapM_ print xs
  print (length xs * 2)
```

You see how the original computation got split up into three separate (and independent!) computations.

1. We turn the loop variable `i1` into a list. We know the bounds are 0 and 9 inclusive, so the loop variable can be represented by the list `[0..9]`.
2. We print the contents of the list, which is the same thing as printing the loop variable every iteration.
3. We calculate "`i`" from what we know about the list, and then print it as well.

The third computation is especially interesting, because it highlights the difference between traditional imperative programming and Haskell, which is a lot about declarative programming.

Adding two to a number every iteration of a list is the same thing as taking the length of the list and multiplying it by two. The big difference, in my eyes, is that I can read `i = length xs * 2` and understand what it means in the blink of an eye. Counting `i` up every iteration of a loop, however, takes some thinking to understand what it really means.

The fact that all three sub-computations are independent means they are a lot easier to test – you can test them one at a time and if they work individually, they will work together as well!

If you meant "similar" in the sense of "similar-looking code", refer to any of the `STRef`/`IORef` answers.

Comment: If I misunderstood you, my defense is that your question was a bit unclear to begin with (hence the diverse answers you have gotten.) It is not at all evident whether you are trying to solve the actual problem you stated in your question, you are trying to solve a problem you think is similar to the one in your question (with the chance of an additional [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)...) or if you are an experienced user curious about the `ST` monad and the like.

Comment: @Alex, looking at this and your other Haskell questions on this site, it is hard to tell whether you are trolling or just have not understood anything you read about Haskell.

Comment: @itsbruce, why did people give me a few sensible answers then? And these are the answers what I was looking for. You don't understand the question?

Comment: It's common for people here to work hard to divine the intent of an ambiguous question and try to offer their best. Many answers on this site are better than the questions that spawned them.

Comment: @Alex, I don't mean any offense whatsoever with this, but your question is sort of like going on a car owners community and asking, "I'm used to my bike tipping over when it stands still. How can I get that kind of behaviour from my car?" The question simply doesn't make sense without *a lot* of context to it. Would you be as surprised if car owners had trouble with that question?

Answer (score 3):

You would use a higher-order function like `forM_`. The name looks a little weird, but it's actually very systematic: the function is called `for`, it works on monads (`M`) and it does not return a value (`_`): `forM_`.

You could use it like this:

```
import Control.Monad

import Data.IORef

main = do i <- newIORef 0
          forM_ [0..9] $ \ i' -> do
            print i'
            i `modifyIORef` (+ 2)
          readIORef i >>= print
```

The `forM_` function itself can be implemented with recursion. Here's a simple way to do it:

```
forM_ []     _ = return ()
forM_ (x:xs) f = f x >> forM_ xs f
```

Of course, using mutable state like this in Haskell is ugly. Not because it *has* to be ugly, but because it's so rarely used. You could imagine a C-like library that looked much nicer; take a look at [this example](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/08/programming-in-c-ummm-haskell-heres.html).

Naturally, the best way to do this in Haskell is to take a more functional approach and forget about mutable variables. You could write something like this instead:

```
main = do forM_ [0..9] print
          print $ sum [i' * 2 | i' <- [0..9]]
```

We could also improve the looping code with some very simple function definitions. Just having a nice operator for reading, setting and modifying `IOVar`s goes a long way:

```
(!) :: (a -> IO b) -> IORef a -> IO b
f ! var = readIORef var >>= f

(+=) :: Num a => IORef a -> a -> IO ()
var += n = var `modifyIORef` (+ n) 

ref :: a -> IO (IORef a)
ref = newIORef
```

This lets us write the loop as so:

```
import Data.IORef

main = do i <- ref 0
          forM_ [0..9] $ \ i' -> do
            print i'
            i += 2
          print !i
```

At this point, it almost looks exactly like OCaml! Quite an improvement for just a few operator definitions.

Comment: Of course, you could go havoc and define `instance (Num a) => Num(IO(IORef a))` to make it look "even nicer". While this does show the power & DSL-capability of Haskell's simple syntax, I don't think such exercises are really useful. If you want it concise, use functional structures. If you want it imperative, don't hide the fact that this is not idiomatic in Haskell.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I agree in principle, but I don't think having nice operators in place of the stupidly verbose `modifyIORef` and friends is really hiding anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad

main = do
   i <- newIORef 0

   let loop = do
        iNow <- readIORef i
        when (iNow < 10) $ do
          print i
          modifyIORef i (+1)
          loop
   loop
```

But obviously, you should avoid this. `mapM_ print [0..9]` works much better.

---

I see you have to `i` variables in there with different increment. Well, it's obvious how to add that here. You can stay to the manual recursion through loop. A little better is replacing one `IORef` by a simple `forM_`. Preferrably, try not to use any `IORef` at all but only functional structures.

Comment: He should actually use `modifyIORef i (+2)` (resp. `mapM_ print [0,2..9]`).

Answer (score 1):

An easy yet flexible way to do a loop is to define a recursive function in a let or where clause:

```
main = loop 0 10
  where
    loop i n | i < n = putStrLn (show i) >> loop (i+2) n
    loop _ _         = return ()
```

This defines a function `loop` of two variables `i` and `n`. The first pattern has a *guard* (after the `|`), which checks the condition (`i < n`). If it is true this branch is selected and `i` is printed to the console before `loop` calls itself again now binding `i` to `i+2`. Otherwise the default branch is selected, which just `returns ()` (=do nothing in the IO Monad).

Implementing loops like this with recursive functions is pretty flexible. If it is easy you want to go with higher-order-functions (such as `for` and `map`), but if you can't figure out how to translate some loop from an imperative setting, recursive functions can usually do the trick.